# How can I detect the row index to find where the error is occuring while changing column type changing?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-cleaning

I am trying to change the column type (e.g. object --> float64)...
However, I found some abnormal value in the cells while using `pd.to_numeric`; therefore, I wanna know how can I return the `row index` where error occurred.

For example,

```
df:
index, col_a, col_b
0       1       2
1       2       3
2     'None'    4
...
20      4       6
21    'None'    9
```

```
pd.to_numeric(df['col_a'])

<<return>> 
error:...
2,21
```

I am using row index for finding the abnormal row. Like this:

```
df:
index, col_a, col_b  abnormal
0       1       2       0
1       2       3       0
2     'None'    4       1
...
20      4       6       0
21    'None'    9       1
22     10     'None'    1
```

How can I efficiently find the abnormal row index?

Comment: use `pd.to_numeric(df['col_a'],errors='coerce')`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the column 'abnormal' is what you want to get? If so, try this:

```
df['abnormal'] = ((df['col_b']=='None') | (df['col_a']=='None')).astype(int)
display(df)
```

The output

```
    col_a   col_b   abnormal
0   1       2       0
1   2       3       0
2   None    4       1
3   4       6       0
4   None    9       1
5   10    None      1
```